# How to disable sound in certain applications?

Tags: windows-7, audio

I hate it when games sometimes play music while being installed.

Is there an easy way to ban selected applications from outputting sound on Windows 7?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From Windows Vista onwards, you can use the Volume Mixer application (double-click on the volume icon in the system tray) to control the sound level of **individual applications**.

Here's a sample screenshot of it:

[image]

You can also run the program by typing `sndvol` from the Run prompt.

It should work for what you would like to do.

Comment: Isn't it a single click on the volume icon?

Comment: @alex : It could be. :)

Comment: @alex A single click only gives you the active output devices (such as speakers and headphones), you still have to click on the 'Mixer' at the bottom to open up the application and do per-application sound control.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 - in the System Tray, double click on the Sound icon and then click Mixer.
You should then see a list of your running apps.
Click on the speaker icon for the individual app to disable sound.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by clicking on the sound icon in the system tray and selecting Mixer.  This will bring up a dialog that will let you indiviually set volume for each open application.